# Retrieve Openshift token when logging in with Keycloak

Tags: openshift, keycloak

I am facing the following problem.

I have to log in users in Openshift using Keycloak and then these users should be able to use the Openshift API using a custom external Web GUI which I made.

When I log in, Keycloak returns a Keycloak JWT-token. But my problem is that with this Keycloak JWT-token I cant use the Openshift API, for that I need an Openshift token, which is a different token. I could get the Openshift token using an http request to -openshiftmaster-/oauth/authorize , But I don't wanna do this cause this second authentication would mean a second login screen for the user. 
Is there a way, once logged in usingKeycloak and in possession of a Keycloak JTW-token, to get the Openshift token without having to authenticate again against Openshift with username and password?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up keycloak as an [open id](http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/06/openshift-ui-console-authentication.html) provider.  [Link 2](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-commons-briefing-35-sso-best-practices-keycloak-integration-openshift/). [Link 3](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html#OpenID).